# How to resign numeric textfields in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I was wondering how could I resign my numeric textfields?

I have a loop in my `viewDidLoad` method that creates the `textfields`, how can I make that whenever I touch anywhere in the view, the app dismisses the keyboard?

Comment: Look at the related questions to your question. Several already answer this question. Please look at the related questions before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do work on background touch of UIView.As I have given steps below.

1)Change UIView's class to UIControl.

[image]

2)Drag control from touch down event of UIControl's event.

[image]

3)Connect to files Owner your background touch IBAction method.And write code to resign first responder.

```
-(IBAction)backgroundtouch:(id)sender
{
    [_yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Call `endEditing:`. This has the advantage that you do not need to know who the first responder actually is! It is a UIView method, and it operates on all the subviews, and you are in a UIViewController, and all these text fields are subviews of it, so you can simply say this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

As for *where* to put that line of code, that depends on what you want to react to. You say "whenever I touch anywhere in the view"; but what view? If it is the overall view of the UIViewController, then, as has already been pointed out, you can just put a UITapGestureRecognizer on `self.view` and have its action method handler call `endEditing:` as shown.

Comment: And here is my book's discussion of gesture recognizers: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_gesture_recognizers

Comment: And here is my book's discussion of the general problem of dismissing the keyboard: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_summoning_and_dismissing_the_keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Same way you resign regular (non-numeric) textfields.

Set your view controller to be a text field delegate, and as soon as editing is finished, you can resignFirstResponder on that text field and the keyboard will dismiss.

[You can also use a UITapGestureRecognizer assigned to the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield) [and then call resignFirstResponder when it's hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809816/uitableview-resign-first-responder-on-outside-touch) (sample code can be found in these two links I've connected to).

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: With the UITapGestureRecognizer, How can I know in the dismiss method, which texfield it should resign? Thanks!

Comment: You either need to keep track of which text field that has begun editing (via a delegate method), or you could simply resign *all* of them.

Comment: And how can I resign all of them? What if I dont keep a record of which textfields I create? :o

Comment: You could iterate through all the subviews of your view controller's content, calling "`resignFirstResponder`" on any subviews that match [`[subview isKindOfClass: [NSTextField class]] == YES`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:); Also, ewwww.