# How to dismiss keyboard by tapping on screen

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am looking for a simple solution in swift to add the ability to tap anywhere on screen and dismiss the keyboard. I read a lot of answers on here but they all throw errors for me. The one I have used before is this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


   let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

This worked with one of my projects but it doesn't seem to work with any others. Whenever I try to add this to other projects I get error Type 'ViewController' has no member 'dismissKeyboard'.

Comment: Can you show your dismissKeyboard method code as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a method above any reference to it. I put this code at the beginning of my files:

```
   func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status and drop into background
    view.endEditing(true)
   }
```

And then whenever I need to reference the .dismissKeyboard I use this inside the viewDidLoad():

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)  // Allows dismissal of keyboard on tap anywhere on screen besides the keyboard itself
```

And make sure to replace 'LoginViewController' with the current View Controller. As per your example, that is just 'ViewController'

If you are looking for a more in depth answer, see this by 7KV7:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5711504/6312593

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one, its very simple solution, frequently used in swift to dismiss the keyboard.

Just add this function, that's it.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) 
{
     self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismiss:"))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func dismiss(gest : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

This is working fine, try it.